# GCDAsyncSocket Swift Xcode 6.2 - Cant make up its mind

Tags: xcode, swift, gcdasyncsocket

I"m trying to instantiate a GCDAsyncSocket connection in Swift and running into a CRAZY error.

```
var socket : GCDAsyncSocket?
typealias dispatch_queue_attr_t = NSObject
var socketQueue = dispatch_queue_create("socketQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: socketQueue)
```

That all seems to work fine.  Then when I try to make a socket connection I get this junk:

### Version 1

```
socket?.connectToHost(host: self.host, onPort: self.port,   error: nil)
```

gives me error message:

**Missing argument for parameter 'withTimeout' in call**

### Version 2

```
socket?.connectToHost(host: self.host, onPort: self.port,  withTimeout: 15, error: nil)
```

**Extra argument 'withTimeout' in call**

## ????

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

The offending was

```
host: self.host
```

oops!